# programmatically adding new variables to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I've carried out this mixed effects model:

```
mtcarsSub <- mtcars[,c("wt", "drat", "cyl")]
library(lme4)
mtcarsME <- lmer(drat ~ (1|cyl) + wt, data=mtcarsSub)
```

I now want to add predictions from the model to `mtcarsSub`. I can add these as new variables like this:

```
mtcarsSub$fixed.effect <- predict(mtcarsME)
mtcarsSub$random.effect.cyl4 <- mtcarsMEFixed + ranef(mtcarsME)$cyl["4",]
mtcarsSub$random.effect.cyl6 <- mtcarsMEFixed + ranef(mtcarsME)$cyl["6",]
mtcarsSub$random.effect.cyl8 <- mtcarsMEFixed + ranef(mtcarsME)$cyl["8",]
```

Note that when adding the predictions from the random effects to `mtcarsSub`, I'm repeating myself 3 times. How can I add the predictions from the random effects programmatically, perhaps using a function and perhaps in a single line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
for( i in c(4,6,8) ) {
  mtcars[[ paste0("random.effect.cyl", i) ]] <- mtcarsMEFixed + ranef(mtcarsME)$cyl[as.character(i),]
}
```

Have alook at `? "[[<-"`

Comment: For the lazy, `[[` indexing allows you to pass strings while `$` does not. So `foo[['bar']]` is equivalent to `foo$bar`. On an somewhat unrelated but interesting note, `[` indexing does not keep names, while `[[` and `$` do.